# Fail test on variables comparison (JSR223 PostProcessor) / Error in data types

Tags: jmeter

How can I compare the value of "plus" in the condition "else if(plus == 4){"

The action takes place in "Logic Controller" → "While Controller"

Initially, the value "plus" is taken from "User Defined Variables". The Jmeter variable "${plus}" will be overwritten until the value of "plus" is = 4

```
def number = 0;

def plus = vars.get("plus").toInteger();
if (vars.get("payment_verification").equals("NOTPAID")){
    
    else if(plus == 4){

        log.error("plus = 4");

    } else {
        number = 100;
        plus++;
        vars.put("number", number.toString());
        vars.put("plus", plus.toString());
        log.info(number);
        log.info(plus);
    }

} else if (vars.get("payment_verification").equals("COMPLETED")){
    
    number = 50;
    vars.put("number", number.toString());
    
} else if (vars.get("payment_verification").equals("NOT_FOUND"){
    log.error("Параметр payment_verification не найден!");
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
    
}
```

Error at the moment:

```
2021-10-19 17:46:32,261 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-10-19 17:46:32,261 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-10-19 17:46:32,274 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2021-10-19 17:46:32,341 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2021-10-19 17:46:32,342 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2021-10-19 17:46:32,342 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-10-19 17:46:32,342 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-10-19 17:46:32,344 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-10-19 17:46:32,344 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-10-19 17:46:32,346 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2021-10-19 17:47:04,841 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script2719.groovy: 6: Unexpected input: '{\n\t\n\telse' @ line 6, column 2.
    else if(plus == 4){
    ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:183) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:211) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:955) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:573) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script2719.groovy: 6: Unexpected input: '{\n\t\n\telse' @ line 6, column 2.
    else if(plus == 4){
    ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:295) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:151) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.collectSyntaxError(AstBuilder.java:4582) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.access$000(AstBuilder.java:341) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder$1.syntaxError(AstBuilder.java:4597) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovyjarjarantlr4.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:44) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovyjarjarantlr4.v4.runtime.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:543) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
```

Comment: You are missing `}` , as `} else if(plus == 4){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need this `else` keyword in `if (plus == 4) {` line
2. There is missing closing parentheses in `} else if (vars.get("payment_verification").equals("NOT_FOUND"){` line
3. Lines like `log.info(number);` will fail as well because you can print only Strings, they need to be changed to something like `log.info(number as String)`

Suggested code fix:

```
def number = 0;

def plus = vars.get("plus").toInteger();
if (vars.get("payment_verification").equals("NOTPAID")) {

    if (plus == 4) {

        log.error("plus = 4");

    } else {
        number = 100;
        plus++;
        vars.put("number", number.toString());
        vars.put("plus", plus.toString());
        log.info(number as String);
        log.info(plus as String);
    }

} else if (vars.get("payment_verification").equals("COMPLETED")) {

    number = 50;
    vars.put("number", number.toString());

} else if (vars.get("payment_verification").equals("NOT_FOUND")) {
    log.error("Параметр payment_verification не найден!");
    prev.setSuccessful(false);

}
```

You can use an IDE like [Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for developing/testing your Groovy scripts.

Also there are [`vars.getObject()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject-java.lang.String-) and [`vars.putObject()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) functions, this way you can avoid conversion of strings to integers and vice versa. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details on this and other JMeter API shorthands.